# 2012 Cervelo R3 downtube cable stop - replacement part

Tags: frames

I need two replacement downtube cable stops for a 2012 Cervelo R3.  Does anyone know where I can get them?  I found 1 for $50 which is outrageous.

Any advice or leads is appreciated!

Greg

Comment: Shopping advise is usually out-of-scope and these are very specific parts, I only found one [shop](https://www.excelsports.com/cervelo-downtube-cable-stops) quickly, however that gave me the Cervelo part number, if that helps (to check with a Cervelo dealer who can order the part or perhaps Cervelo directly: *R3DTCS*